# Why is my Python regex not matching between whitespace?

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract login information from the Linux auth.log and report on it but having trouble with the regex to extract the pertinent information. I thought a group bordered by spaces `(.*)` would match the complete segment of text between those spaces. It works fine for the first word and user name, but for the IP address, it spits out the entire line of text starting from the IP address.  What am I missing?

```
s='Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for user101 from 10.19.36.76 port 36272 ssh2'
s2='Postponed keyboard-interactive for user101 from 10.19.36.76 port 36303 ssh2 [preauth]'

w = re.compile ("(.*) keyboard-interactive.*for (.*) from (.*) ");
m = w.search(s2)
if m:
   print "login by:", m.group(2)
   print "src ip  :", m.group(3)
   print "status  :", m.group(1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
login by: user101
src ip  : 10.19.36.76 port 36303 ssh2 [preauth]
status  : Postponed
```

OR:

```
login by: user101
src ip  : 10.19.36.76 port 36272 ssh2
status  : Accepted
```

Comment: "(.*)" captures also a space, maybe you meant ([^ ]*) ? or, as it has to be an ip "([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
w = re.compile ("(.*?) keyboard-interactive.*for (.*?) from (.*?) ");

                    ^^                              ^^         ^^
```

Make your regex non greedy

Answer (score 1):

Because `(.*)` will match every thing (except new line) after `from`. If you just want to match IP address you can use a character class like following :

```
[\d.]+
```

Or and a much safer approach use following:

```
((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})
```

Comment: or replacing all `(.*)` with `(\S+)` would do the job perfectly.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yep, It has several way but I think the safer one is better.